# how to remove a view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iphone application in which i am adding a view controllers view with an animation like flipfrom left.I was doing it with navigationbarbutton item.when clicking on it i was adding a view controllers view to my rootview.and changing the button amd in that action i am removing that view and adding the previous button like that.but the pbm i need to remove that info view with in a button action inside that view.here is my code for the flipanimation.`

```
- (void)backPressed1
{

    InfoViewController *infoviewcontroller = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.95];

    //[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    //[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];
    //CGRect frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
    [rootview removeFromSuperview];
    //[infoviewcontroller.view setFrame:frame];
    //selfhelpscoresAppDelegate *appdelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [infoviewcontroller viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:infoviewcontroller.view];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"information_btn.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 42, 32);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(backpressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarItem;

    //UILabel *label =[[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Tutorial";
    //label.text = @"";

    //self.navigationController.title = @"";
    [customBarItem release];

}
-(IBAction)backpressed
{
    InfoViewController *infoviewcontroller = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.95];

    //[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    //DailypercentageViewController *pieChart = [[DailypercentageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DailypercentageViewController" bundle:nil];
    //[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.view cache:YES];
    //CGRect frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,370);
    [infoviewcontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:rootview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];  


    //[rearView setFrame:frame];
        //[pieChart viewDidAppear:YES];

    UIImage *buttonImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"information_btn.png"];
    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 setImage:buttonImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 42, 32);
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(backPressed1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button1];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarItem1;
    [customBarItem1 release];




    //UILabel *label1 =[[[UILabel alloc]init]autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.title=@"";
    //label1.text = @"Home";
    //self.title= @"Home";







}
```

`my problem is how i can remove this infoview and came back to the rootview from with in the button action from the infoview?

Comment: Just hide/unhide it. (I didn't read your code or thoroughly read your question)

Comment: define a delegate in info view and set it to the rootviewcontroller and on buttonClick, call a method in rootview that hides the info view...

Comment: @ObaidAbdulMaroof  can u clarrify it pls?

Comment: FYI, it's not a good idea to transition between view controllers by creating a view controller, grabbing it's view and adding it as a subview, and then disregarding the controller itself. Rotation events (presumably amongst others) will not get correctly transmitted to your view. Why not do the proper push/pop of view controllers or the present/dismiss of view controllers and then animate their views accordingly? And, by the way, I'm confused by the `backPressed1` method name. Are you trying to go back to a previous view? Looks like you're going forward, not backward...

Comment: not clear at all!! can you provide a screen shots or edit your long paragraph as steps!!plz

Comment: @M.Othman i just need to go back to previous controllers view with in the button action inside that infoview.thats all.